# Attribute alphabetic sort

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.2.4

I'm on magento 2.2.4 and i've a lot of different **size** in my **attribute size**,

So when i add a new one it's going to the end of the list, so i want to know if there is a way to sort them in alphabetic order ?

For exemple adding a buton for doing this or i don't know what else. If someone can help me it'll be good :D